# Multiple Languages for each subsite on a Multisite

Tags: multisite, multi-language

I need to create a multisite consisting in two Subsites, but I'll also need that each of them have 3 languages.
So just to be clear, the structure is:

```
Multisite

- Subsite 1
- - Portuguese
- - English
- - Spanish

- Subsite 2
- - Portuguese
- - English
- - Spanish
```

I read some things about that on some articles and answers, but nothing seemed to help me in any way. I see many people using subsites for each language in one site on a multisite.

Can I achieve this just by using a localization plugin on each subsite, will that work? I'll need to use a different setup or the only way this is possible is if I make literally two separate websites?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it yet? I don‘t see why this should not work.

Comment: Not yet, this project is yet to come. I'm raising questions to solve at least some of them before the blunt at the start.
I'm thinking about using one theme, two childs and install the multilang plugins on each subsite. If it works, I'll post here :D

Comment: Just started testing it. And apparently it really works, no problem...